# Response giving unwanted characters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a function

```
public function getList(){

    $abc=['a'];
    return response($abc)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
}
```

the response i get in browser is

```
<!-- ["a"]
```

how can I get rid of < !-- that gets concatenated with it everytime

Comment: Check your config files. Every time I get a weird character in every response, that is the first place I look and some file has the extra text.

Answer (score 0):

I want to put it in comment but I have lack of reputation.

I am try to use your code and is works well, In my experience every time I got unexpected character I always to use this. And its works like magic.

```
composer dump_autoload
composer clear-cache
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```